# Htmx (jquery alike) doesn't work on client

Tags: parceljs

I used babel browser presets, and did browser targets in package.json. My packages imported as modules or otherwise aren't working. If I add script tag for htmx/hyperscript then stuff begins to work.

```
"bundleFront": "parcel build ./src/jsLibsClient.js --dist-dir ./src/assets/static",
```

```
  "browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead"

{
    "presets": [
      ["@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead"
      }]
    ]
  }
```